# How to run sonar to analyzing each child module separately

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I have parent pom file with sonar plugin and I want sonar to analyze each child module separately. this is my sonar definition in parent pom :

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>running-sonar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sonar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and with more than 30 modules that inherited the parent pom module, and another pom that builds all of modules together. when I want to run mvn clean install in the build pom, I get this exception :

```
[INFO] Can not execute Sonar

Embedded error: Not a root project: org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectDefinition@94347a9e
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute Sonar
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:103)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a root project: org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectDefinition@94347a9e
    at org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectReactor.<init>(ProjectReactor.java:36)
    at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:98)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to run sonar and aggregate all the results from the parent project, add the `inherited=false` flag in the parent pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <inherited>false</inherited>
    <executions>
    ....
```

Otherwise, every module tries to run the sonar execution as the parent and the plugin complaints.

In case of need, you could still run `mvn sonar:sonar` from a module to analyze **only** its codebase, without aggregating the results of other modules. However, latest versions of Sonar are ready to handle multi-module projects, navigating through each module from the web interface.

Comment: I used this tag, But I still had the problem

Comment: I have tested Maven 2.x with sonar-maven-plugin-1.0 and Maven 3.x with sonar-maven-plugin-2.0 in a multi-module project and both worked fine. Could you verify that there is no sonar-plugin declaration in any of the sub-modules? It should only be declared in the parent pom so every child inherits the configuration but does not run the plugin.